# How to get the count of some column with 'In' status for 'current date' only

Tags: mysql

In prepared statement, I have to get the 'count' of players with 'In' just for the Current date only from the notifyplayers table in MySQL . I have used 'curdate() / current_date()' functions in the query, but count always returned as '0'

Query:

```
select count(1) as count 
from notifyplayers 
where lower(availability) = 'in'  and notifydate = curdate();
```

Please find the table screen shot:

[image]

Could someone please help to figure out about the problem within the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date has a time component, so one method is:

```
select count(1) as count 
rom notifyplayers
where lower(availability) = 'in' and
      date(notifydate) = curdate();
```

However, I would recommend:

```
select count(1) as count 
rom notifyplayers
where lower(availability) = 'in' and
      notifydate >= curdate() and
      notifydate < curdate() + interval 1 day;
```

Comment: I have used the first query and it is working fine. But second query is failing to run, throw error :0 29 14:21:17 select count(1) as count from notifyplayers where lower(availability) = 'in' and notifydate >= curdate() and notifydate < curdate + interval 1 day
 LIMIT 0, 100 Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'curdate' in 'where clause' 0.000 sec

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select count(1) from notifyplayers
where  lower(availability) = 'in'  and date(notifydate) = date(curdate());
```

Comment: Code-only answers do very little to educate SO readers. Your answer may or may not be a correct answer, but it is in the moderation queue after being marked as "low-quality". Please take a moment to improve your answer with an explanation.